# Three-way true-false check

Tags: python

i have 3 variables, `a, b, c`. I want to check if `a` is true, AND if `c` is true but only if `b` is true. if `b` is false, only check `a`.

Eg:

if a is true, but b is false, then return true
if a is true, b is true, c is false, then return false.
if a is false, return false.

what is the most pythonic way of constructing this if condition?

Comment: When solving a boolean logic problem like this one, the first thing to do is to draw the truth table like CorleyBrigman did. You can then isolate your conditions.

Comment: But draw the correct truth table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't strictly python - more of basic boolean checking.
You can take advantage of short-circuiting if you put them in the correct order though.

You have a TT like this:

```
--------------------
| A | B | C | Output
--------------------
| T | F | X | T
| T | T | T | T
| F | X | X | F
| T | T | F | F
```

As you can see, `A == False` always corresponds to a `False` condition. If A is NOT false, `B` is inversely associated with the output condition, and 'C' is directly associated with the output condition.. I'd write it like this:

```
if A and (not B or C):
```

Comment: If you have three boolean values, you must write 2^3 rows. If B and C are true, but A is false, the output is still false.

Comment: @2rs2ts: Yes, but `A == False` short circuits the logic, those rows are not included.

Comment: That problem arises from the question not being clear enough.

Comment: i suppose i could have included the pre-reduced canonical TT. but using x's is pretty standard for reduction.

Comment: @JoelCornett Yes, but that is not how you write the truth table correctly, and it is simply not the case that `C <-> True`.

Comment: at least the second half of that is valid. i'll make an edit.

Comment: +1 for truth table. Just in case, [Karnaugh tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_table) help synthesize shortest boolean expressions from arbitrary truth tables, but here that would be excessive :)

Answer (score 6):

`a and (not b or c)` should also work.

Answer (score 3):

**Edited for new requirements**

You can use an if-then else conditional expression (had wrong syntax earlier)

`a and c if b else a`

Comment: b and (a and c) or a does not work though. Because if a is true, and b is true, but c is false, i want it to evaluate to false.

Comment: That's a conditional expression, not a statement :P

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes in [most BNF grammars](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html), an expression is a statement.

Comment: And Python's got one of those grammars. And we can spend the day arguing about it, but [in Python](http://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-308.html) this construct happens to have a name ;)

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes arguing semantics is fun! :D. I'll update it to be more stanrdard.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
a == b == c == True or b != a == True
```

Comment: Does @C.B. know that `x · y · z` in Python evaluates to `x · y and y · z` for comparison operators `·`?